# How do I make html-like code in an XML file, so I can make things bold or bulleted, for instance?

Tags: asp.net, xml, email

I have some files in XML, within a forum that is .net 4 / c#.  In particular, part of the English.XML file dictates the input of an e-mail that is sent to clients once they're approved for forum use.

I now know you can't use things like:

```
<b> or <ol><li> tags
```

in an XML file, because when I try, it doesn't work.  So if I wanted to make text in an e-mail come out in **bold**, and if I want to **bullet a list**, **how would I do so in an XML file**?  And if I do make a change, is there a way to prevent it from looking strange if the client doesn't have html e-mail enabled in their e-mail program?  Thanks for any guidance you can offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you can keep the format in valid XML format should be fine.
For example

```
<b>Bold</b> 

<ol>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
</ol>
```

The above markup are both valid XML and HTML.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond, Tariq.  I think, for some reason, it doesn't like when I use brackets; instead, I used &lt;&rt; and it worked.  Will this look screwed up if they don't have html enabled in their email?  Regardless, I do appreciate your help and taking the time to respond!

Comment: oops ... meant to type &lt; &gt;

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest using css with XML, please take a look at [CSS for XML tutorial](http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/CSS_for_XML_tutorial) this is fair enough documentation on applying stylesheets in XML

Comment: Thank you for the link, Tom.  I'll definitely look into it, although I'm not too experienced with css.  But this is a good way to learn.  Thank you for taking the time to respond, and offering the link to help me learn!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include a block of html in XML, and it data in a format that XML does not support, like

```
<b> or <ol><li> tags
```

You should mark that section as Character data(CDATA).

When an XML parser encounters the initial `<![CDATA[`, it reports the
content that follows as characters without attempting to interpret
them as element or entity markup. Character references do not work
within CDATA sections. When it encounters the concluding `]]>`, the
parser stops reporting and returns to normal parsing.

```
<![CDATA[<b> or <ol><li> tags]]>
```

This way you can keep your html formatting as required for the mail, and still have valid XML.

Comment: Thank you for that information, Nunes -- although the email seems to be working fine without the <![CDATA[, I'm adding that to my code just to ensure I'm doing things right.  I really do appreciate you taking the time to respond to my question, and to help me learn a little bit more about how to code XML files.  Thanks again!

Comment: Reading more into this, I don't know how it's working without the <![CDATA[ .... I'm at http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp and it seems as if <![CDATA[ is mandatory for unparsed character data.  I have &lt; and &gt; all over, and it's working ... when the & shouldn't be allowed.  I have to read more into this.  Thank you very much for the info, Nunes!

Comment: Do not link to w3schools.com. They have  a lot of wrong information. See [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/)